# what does the word "to promise" mean in the context of casting, compiler?

Tags: java, casting, compilation, terminology

From a java book:

> The compiler checks that you do not **promise** too much when you store a value in a variable. If you assign a subclass reference to a superclass variable, you are **promising** less, and the compiler will simply let you do it. If you assign a superclass reference to a subclass variable, you are **promising** more. Then you must use cast so that your **promise** can be checked at runtime.

I will understand if you can explain to me what does mean "to promise" in a technical matter. I looked in dictionaries but the word can't fit in the context of this paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not standard terminology, but the author seems to be using it to (try to) make it accessible to beginners. (Which isn't easy.) Basically, they're saying that if you have:

```
class Base {
    public void baseMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    public void derivedMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
Base b = new Derived();
```

...because all of the features the `Base` type defines (`baseMethod`) are available on the object you're assigning (the instance of `Derived`). You're "promising" that the object `b` refers to will have `baseMethod`, and it does.

But you can't do this:

```
Derived d = new Base();
```

...because the `Derived` type defines features (`derivedMethod`) that the object you're assigning (the `Base` instance) doesn't have. You're "promising" that the object `d` refers to will have `derivedMethod`, but it doesn't, so you're "promising too much."

---

Re your comment:

> how does casting comes in the second example?

It doesn't come into that example. Casting doesn't change what an object is, just the kind of reference you have to it.¹

But suppose you had something like this:

```
void someMethod(Base obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Derived) { // Just an example, `instanceof` is usually
                                  // an anti-pattern
        Derived d = (Derived)obj;
        // ...
    }
}
```

The method receives an object and has only a `Base` reference to it. But then the code checks and finds that the object is actually a `Derived` (or a subclass of `Derived`), so it uses a cast to change the type of reference it has so that it can use `Derived` features. So casting came come into it in that way.

Again, note that using `instanceof` is an anti-pattern in easily nine out of ten situations. Nine times out of ten, you want to refactor the code so you're passing an interface type to the code that defines just the features that code needs. The tenth situation is rare. :-)

> And will casting be always successful in the second one?

Only if you know, for sure, that the object is of the type you're casting to or a subclass of that type. If you don't know that for sure, casting it may throw a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

---

¹ ...except in the special case of casting primitives (such as `int`) to their wrapper objects (such as `Integer`) and vice-versa. And even then, it doesn't *change* the object, it just creates an object (when casting to the wrapper type) or creates a primitive (when casting to the primitive type).

Comment: "promising to much". Okay, how does casting comes in the second example? And will casting be always successful in the second one?

Comment: @hamzabelmellouki - I've edited the answer to answer that comment's questions.